# FileReader onload function is not firing

Tags: javascript, typescript, filereader

To summarize my problem, I need to read a csv file from an android device. I currently use FileReader from JavaScript. My code was written a month ago and it worked, but when I came back to check the functionality, I saw that my `onload` function is not even firing.

In console log I could see that my object has the function loaded in `onload`, the file is read and its content too. I'll attach below some snippets from my code.

```
readCSVFile(input: HTMLInputElement) {

    var content = this.csvContent;
    const files = input.files;
    console.log("files: ", files);

    if (files && files.length) {

      const fileToRead = files[0];
      console.log("step1");
      var fileReader = new FileReader();

      console.log("state 1: ", fileReader.readyState); //prints undefined, but should have been "0"

      fileReader.onload = this.onFileLoad.bind(this);
      console.log("fileReader: ", fileReader);
      fileReader.readAsText(fileToRead, "UTF-8");
      console.log("fileReader 2: ", fileReader.onload);
      console.log("state 3: ", fileReader.readyState);
   }
}
```

I don't think the 'onFileLoad' file is relevant, but its first line is a `console.log("something")` and I can't see this in my console.
Here are a few outputs from console:

```
fileReader 2:  ƒ (fileLoadedEvent) {
        console.log("step2");
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        this.csvContent = textFromFileLoaded;
        console.log("Continut: ", t…

state 1:  undefined
```

Comment: What browser? What does `console.log(FileReader.toString())`  outputs?

Comment: ```"function () {
    this._readyState = 0;
    this._error = null;
    this._result = null;
    this._progress = null;
    this._localURL = '';
    this._realReader = origFileReader ? new origFileReader() : {}; // eslint-disable-line new-cap
}"``` - Chrome

Comment: Here is your problem: You are dealing with a crappy polyfill.

Comment: The snippet is not valid JavaScript. What is it, pseudo-code?

Comment: It's TypeScript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try without closure. I.E:
fileReader.onload = function(ev){ //here goes your code }.bind(this);

Comment: @LaurentiuAmzarescu there is no way this works better than a bound function. You certainly did omit something in your question if this answer solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Given the output of `FileReader.toString()` being [as per your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734329/filereader-onload-function-is-not-firing#comment100028216_56734329)

> "function () {
>     this._readyState = 0;
>     this._error = null;
>     this._result = null;
>     this._progress = null;
>     this._localURL = '';
>     this._realReader = origFileReader ? new origFileReader() : {}; // eslint-disable-line new-cap
>   }"

This means that you are not dealing with the web-API's FileReader, but rather with some kind of a wrapper object.

Since it's overriding the original name space without having the original behavior, in your position I would simply get rid of whatever does set this wrapper. If you really want to keep this <s>crap</s> though, it seems that its `._realReader` property will be a true FileReader, with which you might be able to interact normally.